# How to determine if the device is Mobile or Desktop?

Tags: php, mobile, desktop

I have read a lot of articles and looked for solutions to detect mobile devices. Actually a came across https://github.com/serbanghita/mobile-detect but it's a quite massive php class.

I actually want a very simple solution. I want to determine if the user's browser is Mobile/iPad/etc OR Desktop. So I want something like this:

```
<?php

require('detector.php');

if(isMobile() === true)
{
   header('mobile.php');
   exit();
}
else
{
   header('desktop.php');
   exit();
}
```

?>

A very simple solution is needed which I can place to any page without installing composer or any php framework.

How is this actually possible?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: do it based off of screen size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you actually tried to use the project you discovered. I'd say that server side mobile detection IS a huge task with plenty of detail checks to ensure the correct outcome.

And using this class is completely easy. From the example directory:

```
require_once '../Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
```

Now you have a variable with one of three values: "tablet", "phone" or "computer", and you can react to this.

Please note that even if you are able to use this library without Composer, it will be updated regularly (as in "once every month"), because new devices get on the market and need to be detected. You will have to update this library at some point. Using Composer makes this very easy.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't notice that it's so easy to use this class! Appriciate your input!

Comment: It's not working when I clicked on Desktop site checkbox in google chrome

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to include that class into your code, [Mozilla indicates that it is "good enough" to search for the string "mobi" in the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent).

```
<?php
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'mobi')!==FALSE) {
    echo 'mobile device detected';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the link with
and in controller you can check with

```
$keybord = app::get('keyboard')
if($keyboard == mobile ){
    redirect ('mobile');
}else{
   redirect ('desktop');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this simple line to be pretty reliable and easy to implement.. without having the need to add one extra class.

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) {
   echo "running on mobile";
}
```