# Eliminate duplicate header tags <h1> on a web page for desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, seo

I have a web page and that page can be viewed both on mobile and desktop. However i have two different css classes like below:

```
<div class=phone-visible>
<h1> .....</h1>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class=phone-hidden>
<h1> .....</h1>
</div>
```

so basically when i open the page on mobile see some content/styles which i write specifically for mobile.
But for SEO purpose, when the page loads i dont want to see the duplicate header tags when i open on a specific device, like i dont want to see the mobile  tag when i open my page on desktop.( basically in view source i dont want this to be displayed) I tried doing in CSS( referring to solution in other posts) but that didnt resolve my issue as those still show up on source.
Any particular approach?

Comment: Have one and hide it if phone - javascript or media queries

Comment: keep only one tag and adjust the CSS using media query ... if you ended with duplicating your code then you made it wrong

Comment: Well if the `<h1></h1>` is always there, why don't you use media queries to make your adjustments at various sizes? Why use two `<h1></h1>` to begin with?

Comment: I did do that using media queries like below. But that did not solve my issue. I am not seeing on page, but however i am seeing in source( view source) of page.

@media screen(max-width: 600px){
.phone-hidden{
visibility: hidden;
display: none;
clear: both;
}
}

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to be able to see the "phone-visible" and "phone-hidden" elements in your source code? If you're okay with them both being in the original source but removing one from the DOM after load, you can use JavaScript. If you only want one to be visible when you use the "View Source" feature, you'll need server-side device detection using a backend language like PHP.

Comment: For what it's worth, see [Can I use multiple times <h1> tag one for desktop another for mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918393/can-i-use-multiple-times-h1-tag-one-for-desktop-another-for-mobile)

Comment: @JonUleis: for SEO duplicate title issue , i was asked to remove. We were trying to do that in Java , knowing user, like if user="Mobile" then this else this. But got feedback that its being misused and abused so trying to do something from html and css perspective

Comment: @Ram Okay - if it's for SEO reasons you will either need to detect mobile devices on the backend and only render the appropriate element, or reexamine the way you're writing your HTML/CSS so you can find a way to reuse one element across desktop/mobile. CSS should be versatile enough for that!

Answer (score 0):

You only need one instance of the H1 tag.

```
<div class="myclass">
<h1> .....</h1>
</div>
```

Then use your responsive CSS to style according to the viewport size.  That's what responsive is all about!  All you would need is to edit the smaller view port size.

So, improving on Yubraj's answer, leave your largest screen size CSS in the main section of your CSS and then add your mobile css here:

```
@media (min-width:750px) {
    .myclass h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-color: #000000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use CSS Media queries to control the UI in different Screen size
below example might help you.

```
@media (min-width:750px) {
    .bigScreen {
        display:block !important;
    }
}

//tabs and bigger screen
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .smallScreen {
        display:block !important;
    }

    .bigScreen {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: will this remove from source code also. I know it works to not display on big screen vs small screen.

Comment: No it wont, If you really want to remove the code based on the screen then you might need to do some server side code to render the UI.
here is the solution based on your requirement i guess:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437868/how-to-determine-if-the-device-is-mobile-or-desktop?rq=1 

hope this will help you..

Comment: there was no solution in that url, but the one suggestion to use USER_AGENT which we already implemented but looking to see if we have any alternative as that approach has a negative feed back due to certain reasons